# ¿como hago en laravel para recuperar el id de un equipo y se guarde como dato en mi tabla partido?

Tags: php, laravel, crud

tengo dos tablas en migraciones la tabla equipo y la tabla partidos, equipo tiene muchos partidos pero partidos solo tiene un equipo, he hecho las relaciones en los models, primeramente tengo un form para crear el equipo, el id se asigna automaticamente cuando se registra en la base de datos, quiero luego a ese equipo registrarle partidos, por lo que en mi tabla de partidos tengo un campo que se llama team_id, pero no logro encontrar como hacerle pasar el id del equipo alli.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto lo que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste (usa el boton [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/591591/edit)).